# How can I pass a comparison function into a Java method?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, comparator

I'm porting some code from Python to Java 8 and am stuck on a method where one of the parameters is a matrix and the others is a comparison function, which in Python is something like `np.gt` or `np.lt`.

I'm finding this difficult to implement in Java, as Java comparisons (Comparator) only operate on complex types, and autoboxing doesn't seem to work.

What I'd like to write is:

```
public static boolean[][] matrix_check(double[][] matrix, Comparator<double> comparator) {
    // ...
}
```

But `Comparator<double>` obviously doesn't work. How should I implement this functionality in Java?

Comment: Use `Comparator<Double>`

Comment: What exactly is "this functionality"? What is the boolean that you're going to set in the result?

Answer (score 3):

Java generics don’t support primitive types.
You need to pass `Comparator<Double>` instead.
You can compare both `double` and `Double` values with such a comparator. Comparing `double` values will leverage auto-boxing.

Answer (score 3):

Having the defined method with [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) as one of the formal parameters means that you can pass a lambda expression in it of a functional interface corresponding to `Comparator`. Don't forget to wrap the `Comparator` around the boxed types, since you cannot use the primitive ones.

The crucial is [`Comparator::compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) which returns `int` and therefore behaves like a `BiFunction<T, T, Integer>`, shall be shortened as a lambda expression (or a method reference in some cases):

```
double[][] doubleArray = ...
Comparator<Double> comparator = (left, right) -> (int)(left - right);  
boolean[][] booleanArray = matrix_check(doubleArray, comparator);
```

The lambda expression might be passed directly as well:

```
double[][] newDoubleArray = matrix_check(doubleArray, (int)(left - right));
```

In the example above, you have to mind the precision lost with casting to `int`. The `double`s are not suitable for the lambda expression explanation. For integers or objects implementing [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) the whole thing would be much easier:

```
Comparator<Integer>  c1 = (l, r) -> l- r;           // l - r results in int
Comparator<String>   c2 = (l, r) -> l.compareTo(r); // implements Comparable by default
Comparator<MyObject> c3 = (l, r) -> l.compareTo(r); // must implement Comparable
```

Comment: `(left, right) -> left - right` is not compatible with `Comparator<Double>`: `left - right` is of type `double`, not `int`.

Comment: @AndyTurner: Thanks for a note, I go fix it :)

Comment: A better comparison would be `Double.compare(left,right)` or simply `Double::compare`

Comment: I don’t understand why this “subtraction equal comparison” myth is so tenacious. a) when you use `(l, r) -> l- r` to compare integers, the distance between `l` and `r` can be larger than the `int` value space and lead to an overflow. b) when you use `(left, right) -> (int)(left - right)` to compare floating point values, the distance might be smaller than one and get rounded to zero. Surely not what you want and also violating the transitivity constraint: comparing `0.5` and `1.0` yields zero, comparing `1.0` and `1.5` yields zero, but comparing `0.5` and `1.5` yields non-zero → broken.

Comment: @Naman using `Double.compare` is not just better, using minus instead is entirely broken.

Comment: The point of my answer is to **not** the doubles comparison but the way to pass `Comparator<T>` correctly. I mentioned that the doubles are not the best way to explain this issue - that's a reason I included the explanation using integers.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `DoubleBinaryOperator`.

```
DoubleBinaryOperator lt = (x, y) -> { if (x > y) return 1; else return -1; };
DoubleBinaryOperator gt = (x, y) -> { if (x < y) return 1; else return -1; };
```

Other binary operations are easily added.

Method definition and comparator usage then looks like:

```
public static Boolean[][] matrix_check(double[][] matrix, DoubleBinaryOperator comparator) {
  if (comparator.applyAsDouble(arg1, arg2) > 0) {
    // Logic if true.
  } else {
    // Logic if false.
 }
```